# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, archivo

El siguiente error que me surge al intentar extraer información de un fichero y no se si es por donde esta almacenado la información o que es:

```
def calcula_notas_finales(nombre_fichero):
''' lee un fichero CSV con los nombres y notas para cada línea del fichero:
     extrae datos y consigue la información del alumno,
    calcula_nota_final y consigue la calificación final  '''            
    with open(nombre_fichero, encoding='utf-8') as fichero:
    for linea in fichero:
        nombre, apellidos, control2,control1,examen = extrae_datos(linea)
        nota_final=calcula_nota_final(control1, control2, examen)
        if nota_final >=5:
            print(nombre, apellidos, nota_final, 'aprobado')
        else:
            
            print(nombre, apellidos, nota_final,'suspenso')
calcula_notas_finales('notas.csv')
```

El error que muestra es el siguiente:

> "C:\Users\Greciano Tena\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Greciano Tena/PycharmProjects/pythonProject9/5.py"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Greciano Tena\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9\5.py", line 40, in 
> calcula_notas_finales('notas.csv')
> File "C:\Users\Greciano Tena\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9\5.py", line 32, in calcula_notas_finales
> with open(nombre_fichero, encoding='utf-8') as fichero:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'notas.csv'

Mi pregunta es porque no lo encuentra si esta en la misma carpeta que el programa, o ¿lo estoy buscando en otro sitio?.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que necesitas, `calcula_notas_finales` que es? una función? desde donde lo estás llamando? El error que te indica es claro, no encuentra el archivo notas.csv en el directorio donde lo estás buscando para analizarlo. Podrías editar y especificar un poco mas? Gracias

Comment: Buenas, si es una funcion, mi pregunta es porque no lo encuentra si esta en la misma carpeta que el programa, o lo estoy buscando en otro sitio? gracias por tu tiempo,

Comment: De casualidad estás usando vscode? Si ese es el caso, probaste ejecutando el programa desde cmd en lugar del editor?

Answer (score 0):

aparentemente parece que el archivo no se encuentra en la misma carpeta que el programa. Acabo de replicar el mismo código con un archivo 'notas.csv' y si funcionó. Te recomiendo utilizar la librería os, en especifico os.listdir para que verifiques si python está considerando el archivo .csv en la misma ruta que tu .py

Answer (score 0):

No se de donde sacas el archivo Notas.csv pero te has fijado que este en formato Windows?
Me ha pasado de trabajar con un script shell en VS Code en mi PC y luego pasarlo a un servidor Linux y a la hora de darle permisos de ejecucion, Linux me decia que el archivo no existia,siendo que estaba en la carpeta. Al final era eso, que estaba en formato windows y no lo encontraba.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que parece, estás situado en un directorio incorrecto.

El interprete de python tomará como directorio de trabajo inicial el directorio desde el que lances el programa. No el directorio del ejecutable `python.exe`, ni el directorio del archivo que estés ejecutando `5.py`.

Es decir. Partiendo de la siguiente estructura de ficheros en tu proyecto:

```
C:/Users/Greciano Tena/PycharmProjects/pythonProject9/
├── venv/
│   └── Scripts/
│       └── python.exe
├── 5.py
└── notas.csv
```

Sólo encontrará el archivo si ejecutas desde el directorio `C:/Users/Greciano Tena/PycharmProjects/pythonProject9/`. Luego:

- Si estás ejecutando el script desde el terminal, asegúrate de que no estés en otro directorio.
- Si estás ejecutando el script con el propio botón "Ejecutar" de PyCharm, asegurate de que el directorio de trabajo esté configurado correctamente.

*Para modificar el directorio de trabajo de un script en PyCharm puedes dar click derecho en el archivo `5.py`, seleccionas "Modify run configuration..." e indicas el directorio en "Working directory"*

[image: Edit working directory]

---

En casos como estos, te puede ser útil añadir un `print` del directorio de trabajo en el script para saber desde dónde está ejecutándose:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```